# Parse Json swift

Tags: json, swift

How to retrieve information in a json with number elements ?
I have to take informations in a Json in swift, but i have elements who are numbers and i don't know how to take the informations of these parts.

In my Json I managed to recover some information, no problems. But those who have a title consists of a number I can not because I can not declare a variable "1" for example. I take the element title in day , but i don't know how to take the informations points in 1 in rankings

The url of the Json is: https://www.lnr.fr/flux/rankings?id_competition=prod2

```
class Classification: Codable {
    let channel : Channel
    let classification : [Day]

    init(channel: Channel ,classification: [Day] ) {
        self.channel = channel
        self.classification = classification
    }
}

class Channel: Codable {
    let title: String

    init (title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
}

class Day: Codable {
    let day: day

    init(day: day) {
        self.day = day
    }
}

class day: Codable {
    let title: String
    let rankings : Equipe

    init(title: String, rankings: Equipe) {
        self.title = title
        self.rankings = rankings
    }
}

class Equipe: Codable {

    let club: Club
    let difference: String
    let points: String
    let points_marques: String
    let points_encaisses: String
    let nombre_matchs_joues: String
    let nombre_matchs_gagnes: String
    let nombre_matchs_nuls: String
    let nombre_matchs_perdus: String

    init(club: Club,difference: String, points: String, points_marques: String, points_encaisses: String, nombre_matchs_joues: String, nombre_matchs_gagnes: String, nombre_matchs_nuls: String, nombre_matchs_perdus: String) {

        self.club = club
        self.difference = difference
        self.points = points
        self.points_marques = points_marques
        self.points_encaisses = points_encaisses
        self.nombre_matchs_joues = nombre_matchs_joues
        self.nombre_matchs_gagnes = nombre_matchs_gagnes
        self.nombre_matchs_nuls = nombre_matchs_nuls
        self.nombre_matchs_perdus = nombre_matchs_perdus
    }
}

class Club: Codable {
    let name: String
    let url: logo

    init(name: String, url: logo) {
        self.name = name
        self.url = url
    }
}

class logo: Codable {
    let url: String

    init(url: String) {
        self.url = url
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 4 parsing json numeric keys with 1+n amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51272108/swift-4-parsing-json-numeric-keys-with-1n-amount)

Answer (score 2):

You can use custom CodingKeys for that; checkout [Encoding and Decoding Custom Types](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/archives_and_serialization/encoding_and_decoding_custom_types)

Example:

```
struct Foo: Codable {
    var bar: String
    var baz: Int

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case bar = "1"
        case baz = "2"
    }
}

let json = "{\"1\":\"bar\",\"2\":\"baz\"}".data(using: .utf8)
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
let foo = try decoder.decode(Foo.self, from: json)
// foo.bar = 'bar'
// foo.baz = 'baz'

// this also works with encoding
let foo = Foo(bar: "MyBar", baz: "MyBaz")
// foo encodes to {"1":"MyBar", "2":"MyBaz"}
```

Nested example
    struct FooBar: Codable {
        var foo: Foo
        var bar: String
        var baz: Int
    }

```
struct Foo: Codable {
    var bar1: String
    var bar2: String
    var bar3: String
    var bar4: String
    var bar5: String
    var bar6: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case bar1 = "1"
        case bar2 = "2"
        case bar3 = "3"
        case bar4 = "4"
        case bar5 = "5"
        case bar6 = "6"
    }
}
```

This is the same as the json structure:

```
{
  "foo": {
    "1": "One",
    "2": "Two",
    "3": "Three",
    "4": "Four",
    "5": "Five",
    "6": "Six"
  },
  "bar": "Barrr",
  "baz": "Bazz"
}
```

Comment: I don't understand how to use it. I have to use the struc and the case but how i can join this in my case

Comment: You don't have to use a struct, but for your use case i'd probably use structs instead of classes (checkout [Building Better Apps with Value Types in Swift](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/414/) for more info). What will happen now is that json `{"1":"bar","2":"baz"}` will be transformed into a `struct` `Foo.bar == 'bar' and baz == 'baz'`

Comment: I am sorry but i don't understand more,
in my json and my code , what did i have to add to did this exactlys?

Comment: Look at my given example and your JSON output closely. You say that the key `rankings` is a single `Equipe`, this is not the case, rankings is a Dictionary of 16 keys ("1" to "16"). So you'll need another class 'in between'. It would be better to make the `rankings` an actual array instead of a dictionary, then you could do: `rankings: [Equipe]` and you wouldn't need the CodingKeys

Comment: class day: Codable {
    let title: String
    let rankings : [Equipe]
    
    init(title: String, rankings: [Equipe]) {
        self.title = title
        self.rankings = rankings
    }
}

like this ?
But it don't work

Comment: Nope, because the JSON you're supplying isn't an array, that wouldn't work. StackOverflow isn't a platform to write your code for you, have a good look at the JSON you're trying to parse, and my example. I can extend it a bit more.

Comment: I've added even more examples.. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CodingKeys

Example:

```
struct MyModel: Codable {

    let first: String

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
       case first = "1"
    }
 }
```

Comment: Do you have an exemple for my Json ?

Comment: The problem is: are the numbers theoretically infinites?

Comment: If so, you can also decode this json as a dictionary of [Int: Model]