# Parsing json data containing indexes using swift?

Tags: json, swift

How to parse this json data in swift?
The problem is that it is indexed, which is why I don't how to parse it.

```
[{
    "1": {
        "id": "30",
        "name": "Jhon"
    },
    "2": {
        "id": "41",
        "name": "Tim"
    }
}]
```

Comment: Couple of questions. Why are the 1 and 2 objects not directly inside of an array? Are you only expecting 2 objects in this json?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift 4 parsing json numeric keys with 1+n amount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51272108/swift-4-parsing-json-numeric-keys-with-1n-amount)

Comment: This is not an easy to handle json format. You don't need to contains "1","2" in json

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
let res = try JSONDecoder().decode([[String:Root]].self, from: data)
```

---

```
struct Root: Codable {
  let id, name: String
}
```

if it could be

```
[   {
        "id": "30",
        "name": "Jhon"
    },
      {
        "id": "41",
        "name": "Tim"
    }
]
```

Then do

```
let res = try JSONDecoder().decode[Root].self, from: data)
```

Comment: That is the problem my json is indexed

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you should ask yourself is if you can get that server fixed so it sends a more reasonable JSON back. Having worked in systems that return less than desirable data and having no control whatsoever on the resulting format, I know that sometimes it is impossible.

If you or a coworker wrote that code, I strongly recommend you to fix it.

If you cannot get your server fixed to send a better JSON due to having no control over it, you will need to write a bit of ugly code to get your data.

You can start by defining a structure that will hold your basic data. The following code snippets take some shortcuts to simplify the answer. Always deal with nils and do-try-catch responsibly.

```swift
struct UserInfo: Codable {
  let id: String
  let name: String
}
```

You can then decode it directly as such:

```swift
let badContainer = try! JSONDecoder().decode([[String: UserInfo]].self, from: badJsonData)
```

Then to access your data:

```swift
let containerEntry = badContainer.first!

for (key, value) in containerEntry {
  print("\(key): ID \(value.id) - NAME \(value.name)")
}
```

You now have full access to your data, but I strongly urge you to fix this at the core level. This is the type of problems that cause many more headaches later on.

The full Playground I created is attached bellow:

```swift
let badJson =
"""
[{
    "1": {
        "id": "30",
        "name": "Jhon"
    },
    "2": {
        "id": "41",
        "name": "Tim"
    }
}]
"""

let badJsonData = badJson.data(using: .utf8)!

struct UserInfo: Codable {
  let id: String
  let name: String
}

let badContainer = try! JSONDecoder().decode([[String: UserInfo]].self, from: badJsonData)

let containerEntry = badContainer.first!

for (key, value) in containerEntry {
  print("\(key): ID \(value.id) - NAME \(value.name)")
}
```